# Change Android device font size without rebooting

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

My app is the home launcher, meaning the user cant get back to the main Android menu from my application (its a business application). I want to change the system font size for the entire device out of simplicity of it being a single line of code to change everything.

Im changing my device font size via...

```
        Settings.System.PutFloat(ContentResolver, Settings.System.FontScale, 0.5f);
```

This works great and it updates it, however, it requires a device reboot to take place. When I call the GetFloat method it does show the correct value, but until i do a full device reboot it doesnt take place visually. Is there any way I can change it without a reboot or to do a soft refresh that doesnt require a full reboot?

Comment: to me, your question seems a bit unclear. Are you trying to affect font size for the entire device, for just your app as it starts up, or allowing user to change font size from a settings dialog?

Comment: @PaulStoner Sorry about the clarity. My app is the home launcher, meaning the user cant get back to the main Android menu from my application (its a business application). I want to change the system font size for the entire device out of simplicity of it being a single line of code to change everything.

Comment: not a problem. I would suggest you edit your question and provide this more meaningful information. This will allow others to assist you

Comment: Is there any suggestion you may have in regards to how I can solve my issue?

Comment: unfortunately, no. I am but a very basic student of Android and/or Xamarin programming.

Comment: I don't believe that is possible. You could however use Styles to set the font size for the controls you use. See: http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-styles-and-themes-tutorial

Comment: The app has already been created and there is a LOT of stuff already in it. I dont want to have to go through and change everything thats already been created so I figured it would be best to do this solution. I will just have the users be prompted for a restart i suppose.